# android:clipToPadding not working from theme, but works as a style

Tags: android, themes

I'm using themes in my application to customize views, and right now everything seems to work fine, except setting `android:clipToPadding` for a `GridView`, but what is most surprising is the fact that it works as expected if I set it directly or using a style

My style looks like this (actually I set a lot more parameters but it's irrelevant for this problem):

```
<style name="GridViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.GridView">
    <item name="android:clipToPadding">false</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/grid_item_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/grid_item_padding</item>
</style>
```

This is the way I want to set it:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:gridViewStyle">@style/GridViewStyle</item>
</style>
```

and all of the parameters work - except mentioned `android:clipToPadding`

now if I set the style directly:

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@style/GridViewStyle"
/>
```

or if I just set it like this:

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
/>
```

then it works.

Does anyone have an idea why style and setting directly is working, but theme is not?

Comment: I have the exact same behavior. Did you find a solution?